# Android API: How to access system file programmatically with rooted device?

Tags: android, root

After granted my application superuser right by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`

I still can't access system files like files in /bin

```java
File file = new File("/bin");
File[] fileList = file.listFiles(); // fileList is a null array
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The app itself (the code you develop in Java/Kotlin) never gets root permissions. Only within a root shell opened by the app you can execute standard Linux command-line tools to perform root actions.

Therefore executing `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` has absolutely no effect on your app. It just starts a root shell and as there is no command to execute directly closes it.

In your case I would simply assume the `/bin` folder does not exist. Most likely you are searching for `/system/bin` or `/system/sbin`. Listing one of those folders does not require root permissions. Also listing `/` does not require root permissions. You can use Java code or `adb shell ls -la /` to list files in the file-system to see what directories actually exist.

Comment: Thanks for your respond!
so what you mean is there's no official api support for root permission
what I can do is using shell for root permission, right?

Comment: @RayLiu There are libraries available which simplify executing commands with root permissions, see e.g. https://github.com/topjohnwu/libsu. BTW: Feel free to upvote and/or accept my question if it was helpful.